# AngularJS - complex filter base on categories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

All I can find about AngularJS filters is simple examples about simple filters (mostly on a single field's value).

What I'm after though is somewhat more complex. Imagine you have an array of the following JSON objects:

```
{
    "Categoria": "Informática",
    "Title": "Consultor DBA Oracle",
    "professionalarea": {
        "idAreaProfissional": 1,
        "description": "IT"
    },
    "Horario": "Estágio Profissional"
}, {
    "Categoria": "Finanças",
    "Title": "Gestor de Projeto",
    "professionalarea": {
        "idAreaProfissional": 1,
        "description": "IT"
    },
    "Horario": "Full-time"
}
```

My goal is to create a frontend interface that allows me to cumulatively apply various kinds of filters to those JSON objects.

I have one example I was following:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/840/)

Answer (score 0):

For filters there are many options:

**string:** The string is used for matching against the contents of the array. All strings or objects with string properties in array that match this string will be returned. This also applies to nested object properties. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !.

Example (search is a simple search string, search in *all* fields):

```
ng-repeat="player in filteredPlayers | filter:search"
```

**Object:** A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property name ($ by default) can be used (e.g. as in {$: "text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its nested object properties. That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above. The special property name can be overwritten, using the anyPropertyKey parameter. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !. For example {name: "!M"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name not containing "M".

Example (filtering *2 specific fields* with specific values)

```
ng-repeat="player in filteredPlayers | filter:{Categoria: cat,Title: tit}"
```

Note that a named property will match properties on the same level only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same level or deeper. E.g. an array item like {name: {first: 'John', last: 'Doe'}} will not be matched by {name: 'John'}, but will be matched by {$: 'John'}.

**function(value, index, array):** A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.

The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

Example (filtering with a *custom function* `selection()` )

```
ng-repeat="player in filteredPlayers | filter:selection"
```

In your app script (custom function, filter only items with some optional values):

```
$scope.selection=function(value, index, array){
  if ( value.Horario == 'Full time' || value.Horario == 'Estágio Profissional'){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i need the if return me the value in my json automatic but i will try change my code because as i have doesnt' work

Comment: In my example jsfidlle works well but when i try put professionalarea.description doesn't work

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with that case to check what could be wrong?

Comment: in my post i have one jsfiddle